# Laptop screen replacement

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, led, laptop-repair

I have [this screen](http://www.panelook.com/N173HGE-L11_Chimei%20Innolux_17.3_LCM_parameter_12343.html) and the "Full HD" resolution is too much for my eyes. I'd like to get a screen with smaller resolution. Will [this model](http://www.panelook.com/N173FGE-L21_Chimei%20Innolux_17.3_LCM_parameter_12342.html) work? Or N173HGE-L11 (please use search on that site, I can't post more than 2 links)? I see that "Lamp Voltage" is different between N173HGE-L11 and N173FGE-L21, but "Input Voltage for Panel" is the same. What does it mean? Are they compatible?

Answer (score 5):

Are your referring to the actual resolution of the screen, or something else like the pixel density? The panels could possibly be interchangeable, through it looks like the interfaces they use are not the same, and the higher resolution panel takes more voltage than the lower one does, so you may be at risk of frying the new panel.

Why don't you simply reduce the screen resolution your running your OS at?

Comment: Exactly. If your screen has too high of a DPI at its native resolution and the feature size is too small for you to be able to read normal font text etc, the recommended solution is to either use large fonts (the OS can do this for you) or reduce screen resolution. Much cheaper than replacing the panel.